# How do I add a array value to existing jQuery cookie?

Tags: jquery, cookies

Im using https://github.com/carhartl/jquery-cookie to set cookies and now I need to set multiple values(array) in one cookie and then later be able to check if any of those values are equal to another value.

So lets say I set a cookie with this:

```
var date = new Date();
var minutes = 60;
date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));
$.cookie('amnotiser', '111', { expires: date });
```

Then later I want check if the cookie has a value, for example I want to check if the cookie has a value of 222, and if not, then add it without deleting the existing values. And if it already has the value of 222 then do nothing.

```
var amnotiser = $.cookie('amnotiser');

if(amnotiser===222){
 //do nothing...
}else{
 add the value to the cookie...
}
```

Ok so I can add a value with this:

```
var amnotiser = $.cookie('amnotiser');
var newvalue = "222";
thearray = new Array();
thearray.push(amnotiser+","+newvalue);
console.log(thearray)
$.cookie('amnotiser', thearray);
```

And this adds 222 so it looks like this: ["111,222"] Good!

So how do I now loop through the array to see if it has a specific value?

Any input appreciated, thanks.

Comment: So you want the value to be `['111', 'somethingelse']` ?

Comment: I want the value to become ['111','222'] and so on, so I can add multiple values to an existing cookie.

Comment: Then I would suggest changing the initial value to `['111']`, and when you need to add more, you would just push the value to the array, and set it back on the cookie

Comment: Ok thanks, but I tested with this: $.cookie('amnotiser', '["111"]');
var amnotiser = $.cookie('amnotiser');
console.log(amnotiser)
amnotiser.push('222') 
var amnotiser = $.cookie('amnotiser');
console.log(amnotiser) but I get an error saying "amnotiser.push is not a function. "

Comment: I would assume the value in the cookie is a string.  You will probably have to stringify the value when you set it, and parse it when you retrieve it

Answer (score 0):

The trick is in using `JSON.stringify()` and `JSON.parse()`, like this:

```
var date = new Date();
var minutes = 60;

date.setTime(date.getTime() + (minutes * 60 * 1000));

const setAmnotiser = (data, date) => {
  let arr = []
  arr = [...getAmnotiser()]
  if (!checkForValue(arr, data)) arr.push(data)
  $.cookie('amnotiser', JSON.stringify(arr), {
    expires: date
  });
}

const getAmnotiser = () => {
  if ($.cookie('amnotiser')) return JSON.parse($.cookie('amnotiser'))
  return []
}

const checkForValue = (arr, data) => {
  return arr.includes(data)
}

console.log('0', getAmnotiser())
setAmnotiser('111', date)
console.log('1', getAmnotiser())
setAmnotiser('222', date)
console.log('2', getAmnotiser())
setAmnotiser('222', date)
console.log('3', getAmnotiser())
```

Here's a fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mukagergely/rxz6hov3/

Unfortunately I couldn't use **$.cookie()** in a SO snippet, that's why I linked the working fiddle.